# Remove one Item in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have some method like:

```
public void RemoveItem(ObservableCollection<SomeClass> collection, SomeClass instance)
{
    if(collection.Contains(instance))
    {
        collection.Remove(instance);
    }
}
```

First, even the collection contains the instance, the `if` sentence still return `false`.

Second, I delete the if sentence, just make the collection can remove the instance. And after the execution the collection still kept its original items, which still include instance.

Is it the Reference problem, but how to fix it? I just want to remove one item from the ObservableCollection and keep its Observable functionality (**which puzzled me [here](http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection)**).

Comment: `Is it the Reference problem` - probably, yes. Post your full code. Where do `collection` and `instance` come from? and how are you constructing the collection?

Comment: Do you have redefine the Equals method in SomeClass?

Comment: Don't do `if (collection.Contains(instance))
    {
        collection.Remove(instance);
    }`. The method `Remove` will check for you if there is something to remove, and simply return `false` in case there was not.

Answer (score 46):

Your problem is that you are trying to remove an object from the collection *that is not in that collection*. It might have the same property values, but *it is not the same object*. There is a simple way around this if your object has a uniquely identifiable property, such as `Id`:

```
public void RemoveItem(ObservableCollection<SomeClass> collection, SomeClass instance)
{
    collection.Remove(collection.Where(i => i.Id == instance.Id).Single());
}
```

The idea is that we are getting the *actual* item from the collection and then passing that into the `Remove` method.

Comment: Maybe you should use `collection.Remove(collection.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == instance.Id));` instead. There is no need to have a `Where` directly followed by a `First`, `Single`, etc. And in his original code it appears that the `instance` might not be there. So you should not use `Single` which will explode if no match is there. In either version, it is implicitly assumed that `collection` contains no `null` values of `SomeClass`.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that dude... I am well aware of these things, but was just trying to keep the example simple. For other users reading this, check out the comment above.

Answer (score 9):

If the item you intend to remove has something like a code/id you could compare to other item, you could do something in the lines of:

```
foreach (var item in itemSet)
{
  if (item.ItemID == itemToCompareTo.ItemID)
  {
    itemSet.Remove(item);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you must add `break;` immediately after the remove statement. Otherwise the enumeration will continue, and that would lead to an exception because the collection has changed during `foreach`.

Comment: Indeed @JeppeStigNielsen, I was doing it in my head and I missed that

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a reference problem, indeed.
You may have to **override Equals (and GetHashCode) methods** in order to the ObservableCollection to be able to find the instance, even if it is not the same reference.

The reason is because the default implementation of the Equals() method checks to see if the two objects have the same reference.

**Note** : be careful when overriding Equals method. You will have to also override GetHashCode, because the default implementation of the GetHashCode() method returns an integer based on the object's reference and is not based on the values of instance (and class) variables of the object.

No matter how many times the values of its instance variables (data fields) change, the hash code calculated by the default implementation does not change during the life of the object. That's why we always implement GetHashCode() when you are overriding the Equals() method.

More about this on msdn : [Object.Equals Method (Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47)