# How can I delete an object from an XML file

Tags: c#, collections

I have a problem. I have an XML file and there I save projects. I try, for example to delete the project2 but I have not found anything that works. Is there a good way to solve it easily and cleanly?

c# Code:

```
private void WriteToXML(XmlSerializer xs, ObservableCollection<ProjektListItem> projekte)
{
    using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@".\LastUsedProjects.xml"))
    {
        projekte.Remove(SelectedItem);
        xs.Serialize(wr, projekte);
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfProjektListItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ProjektListItem>
    <_Name>Projekt1</_Name>
    <_Path>C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Projekt1.xml</_Path>
    <_Date>12.07.2019 10:46</_Date>
    <_Source />
  </ProjektListItem>
  <ProjektListItem>
    <_Name>Projekt2</_Name>
    <_Path>C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Projekt1.xml</_Path>
    <_Date>12.07.2019 10:46</_Date>
    <_Source />
  </ProjektListItem>
</ArrayOfProjektListItem>
```

SelectedItem comes from a ComboBox in which i select my project. I know how to remove it from the Collection but i dont know how to update the xml. The XML file is the Illustration from my collection. I remove the selectedItem from the Collection and now i have to remove it from the xml file respectively update / override it in the XML File.

Comment: `Collection<T>.Remove(T item)` does return a boolean with the result of the removal. Could you edit your question and add the result of that call?

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question and explain what `SelectedItem` is and where it comes from. Also, see this question: [Remove Item in ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403162/remove-one-item-in-observablecollection)

Comment: The [Collection.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.remove?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) documentation explains that `Remove` uses the default comparer to find which item to remove. This means that unless `ProjektListItem` overrides `Equals`, `Remove` will use reference comparison and only remove an item if it's already in the list. XML has nothing to do with this problem

Comment: To avoid the reference comparation if not `Equals` override is provided (as Panagiotis's comment mentions), you could also consider using `ObservableCollection<T>.RemoveItem(int index)`